# How to load a webpage in the whole window rather than a frame when working framesets in html?

Tags: php, html, web, google-web-designer

I am working on my website. I am using ***frameset*** in site. I need to load some pages in specific frames which are working fine. But On particular page i need to load in in the whole window. But it is loading in the frame only. How to solve this issue?

Here is the code for my framesets

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home: Rineva CRM </title>
    </head>

    <frameset rows="15%,*">
        <frame src="banner.html">
        <frameset cols="15%,*">
            <frame src="menu.html" target=>
            <frame src="main.html" name="MainWindow">
        </frameset>
    </frameset>

</html>
```

Here is the code for menu page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main/menu.css">
        <title>Menu </title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="main.html" target="MainWindow">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="new.html"target="MainWindow">New Customer</a></li>
                <li><a href="search.html"target="MainWindow">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="ticket.html"target="MainWindow">Tickets</a></li>
                <li><a href="127.0.0.1:81/wordpress"target="MainWindow">Knowldege Base</a></li>
                <li><a href="list.html"target="MainWindow">Customer List</a></li>
                <li><a href="settings.html" target="MainWindow">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Sign Out </a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to last link ***logout.php*** to load in the whole window, rather in the menu frame. 
How to solve this issue? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: target="_top" Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Let me check that.

Comment: @VA79 This worked so fine. Thanks.